# Numpy Arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have this code that contains a for loop to print out this result for me.
Could I transfer this to Numpy Array instead of for loop and less memory?

```
categorical__unique = df.select_dtypes(['object']).columns 

for col in categorical__unique:
     print('{} : {} unique value(s)'.
           format(col, df[col].nunique()))
```

I am trying to make this categorial_unique value to an array and then use the functions of the NumPy array instead of for loop.

Comment: do you want unique values across all `dtype=object` columns or do you still want to find unique values in each column?

Comment: No I just want it for the object data types in all the values the I have in my dataset. but I am thinking just to use NumPy in my EDA analysis just to make sure I have covered most of python skills.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a dataframe into a matrix you have to use the "to_numpy" function from pandas

`categorical_unique = df.select_dtypes(['object']).to_numpy()`

Comment: and then I will be able to consider it as a NumPy array and implement all np.array functions ?

Comment: if there are other columns in the dataframe that ***are not*** `dtype=object` but a more specific class they will be upcast to object. Not sure if that is what the OP wants.

Comment: This seems to me to be what you have asked for, which is to have the df object info in an numpy array. However, since your question is very vague and I don't know what's inside the "df" dataframe, or even what you want as the output of your code, it's hard for me to say.